Need help with modelling a peculiar window sill
I want to (re) create a peculiar type of window sill I saw in an old 1999 game.
I dont have much experience with blender.
Any help would be appreciated, I also attached a picture of my current mesh geometry (vertices,edges,faces)
Geometrically the object is the 1/4 of a sphere or some kind of ellipsoid. My first idea was to create this geometry and attach both objects with help of some Boolean Operator. I find this to be a brute forced solution and dont like it much...Is there some better more natural solution to this problem? Any ideas?  


No i think joining them with a boolean mod and then cleaning them up is the most straightforward option. I would only say maybe make sure the geometry density is consistent between the two objects to make it as clean as possible (like don't use a 32 sided sphere booleaned into the side of a 32 sided cylinder that's 5x as big. make sure the spacing between the rings on each component approximately match eachother in world space.)

But also don't always feel like you have to join every object and model 100% watertight at all times. If you can just "set" a half sphere on the front of this cylinder shape and have it look decent then that totally works. Like houses in general aren't carved out of one solid block of clay, they're usually made up of small parts joined together. Try to think of the way you construct buildings this way and it will not only be easier for you but often look more natural as well.

This is just 3d modelling in general. There are hundreds of ways to model a shape like that. The real answer is that you need to watch some tutorials, get familiar with the modelling tools available and then practice. At this moment you lack familiarity with the tools available, mainly all the stuff in these menus in Edit mode:

Learning them would answer lots of questions.
In this particular case modelling that particular form could go something like this:
Duplicate some edges( Shift  +  D ) and fill them with a face( F ), or duplicate a face below the window and slide one edge( Shif  +  V ,  C  locks direction so you can extend outwards while in operation) to make a single face below the window that matches the slope of the wall. Don't move it, or move it inwards to the wall a bit so you don't have to worry about wall curvature not matching it. If it's going to be stylized cartoon style, you really don't need to worry about it being single connected mesh or anything like that.

Extrude it( E ), but constrain the movement axis to global Y by hitting  Y  while moving it:

Flatten the face in Y axis by scaling( S ) it in Y axis( Y  in scale operation) to 0(hit  0  on the numpad while in scale operation). You can move it a bit further so there is definitely enough space for bevels that is the next step. It's OK to move the whole thing back later:

Select the lower edges:

Bevel them( Ctrl  +  B ), adjust segments with scroll wheel:

You can adjust the result by moving vertices or scaling it


Fantastic answer! Thank you very much for your time.

@Prutsikas Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum.  Please don't just reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted.
